# работа со списком классов унаследованных от интерфейса

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте, у меня есть интерфейс:

```
public interface IApiConnect
{
    string Url { set; get; }
}
```

И есть список классов, уноследованных от этого интерфейса

```
public List<IApiConnect> APIs = new List<IApiConnect>();
public string Url { set; get; }
public ApiConnections(string url)
{
    APIs.Add(new ScreenShoot(url));         
    APIs.Add(new YandexIndex(url));
    APIs.Add(new UrlSearchResult(url));
}
```

Как взаимодействовать с экземплярами классов, если доступно только свойство Url, а мне необходимы внутренние свойства каждого из объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать приведение к нужному типу. Например, с помощью оператора as.

Answer (score 2):

Есть оператор `OfType<T>`.
Если нужно для всех ссылок на яндекс выполнить какой то метод:

```
foreach (var yandex in APIs.OfType<YandexIndex>())
  yandex.DoIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный подход — обработка должна вестись не при помощи анализа конкретного типа (это источник бесконечного количества ошибок и боли), а при помощи *виртуальных методов*. Необходимость downcast'а — признак проблем в архитектуре.

Вынесите нужную логику обработки в метод каждого из классов, и потребуйте его наличия через интерфейс. Если эта логика не относится к самому классу, наденьте нужный wrapper. Ну и если вам по логике нужно производить какие-то действия только с `UrlSearchResult`, то просто не бросайте все классы в один и тот же список.